# RxJava's scan overrides the current value with initialValue on every new subscriber

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-viewmodel

Using this code to emit `states` from the `ViewModel`:

```
private val stateCommandRelay: PublishRelay<StateCommand> by lazy {
    PublishRelay.create<StateCommand>()
}

val states: Flowable<STATE>  by lazy {
    stateCommandRelay
            .doOnNext { Log.d(className(), "----> ${it.javaClass.simpleName}") }
            .scan(initialState()) { previous: STATE, command: StateCommand ->
                Log.d(className(), "Reducing with command: ${command.javaClass.simpleName}")
                reducer().reduce(previous, command)
            }
            .doOnNext { Log.d(className(), "STATE: $it") }
            .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
            .replayingShare()
}
```

This is subscribed using the following code in `Activity`/`Fragment`:

```
viewModel.states.subscribeBy(onNext = { render(it) })
```

It works well when receiving `StateCommands` and emitting new states, the initial `state` is propagated without waiting for the first stateCommand.

A problem arise when `states` is resubscribed to. The `initialValue` is re-emitted, overriding the current state and basically resetting the state.

From the logs I can see that no `StateCommands` are passed from `stateCommandRelay`, neither is the `reducer.reduce()` method called, it just emits this new value and subsequent calls to `reducer.reduce()` will have this resetted state as `previous`.

Am I missing something? I thought it would only be called on the first subscribe, which `replayingShare()` should take care of making it happen only once.

Comment: ReplayingShare will always replay the last emitted value to new subscribers. See the marble diagram [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxReplayingShare).

Comment: But initialValue is not the latest item emitted, it's the first one and it should be overwritten by the new items that scan emits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        .scan(initialState()) { previous: STATE, command: StateCommand ->
            Log.d(className(), "Reducing with command: ${command.javaClass.simpleName}")
            reducer().reduce(previous, command)
        }
        .replay(1)
        .autoConnect(0)
        .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
        //.replayingShare()
```